# Add login to a menu in orchard cms

Tags: authentication, menu, orchardcms

I've just installed a new orchard site, and I'm just starting to get to know the system.

I'm trying to add a "Login" link to my menu, with no success... can anyone please explain to me how to achieve it?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a custom link with a value of /Users/Account/Logon